# How do I call function inside another function?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

If I have two functions, (one inside the other);

```
def test1():
    def test2():
        print("test2")
```

How do I call `test2`?

Comment: You should clarify your question: do you mean how to call it from inside `test1`, or from outside?  As the two answers show, the answer is either "the obvious way" or "you can't".

Comment: If you want to *use `test2` outside `test1`*, you can `return` it like any other object - that's how decorators work.

Comment: Would I return it with `return test2`? @jonrsharpe

Comment: @zachgates yes, exactly. Functions are first-class in Python; they are just callable objects, you can pass them around like anything else.

Comment: What you have there is a function *definition* within a function definition. The inner one is executed every time the outer one is executed, and creates a new *function* every time. Which of the potentially infinite number of functions you want to call?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can call it in this way too:

```
def test1():
    text = "Foo is pretty"
    print "Inside test1()"
    def test2():
        print "Inside test2()"
        print "test2() -> ", text
    return test2

test1()() # first way, prints "Foo is pretty"

test2 = test1() # second way
test2() # prints "Foo is pretty"
```

**Let's see:**

```
>>> Inside test1()
>>> Inside test2()
>>> test2() ->  Foo is pretty

>>> Inside test1()
>>> Inside test2()
>>> test2() ->  Foo is pretty
```

**If you don't want to call the** `test2()`**:**

```
test1() # first way, prints "Inside test1()", but there's test2() as return value.
>>> Inside test1()
print test1()
>>> <function test2 at 0x1202c80>
```

**Let's get more hard:**

```
def test1():
    print "Inside test1()"
    def test2():
        print "Inside test2()"
        def test3():
            print "Inside test3()"
            return "Foo is pretty."
        return test3
    return test2

print test1()()() # first way, prints the return string "Foo is pretty."

test2 = test1() # second way
test3 = test2()
print test3() # prints "Foo is pretty."
```

**Let's see:**

```
>>> Inside test1()
>>> Inside test2()
>>> Inside test3()
>>> Foo is pretty.

>>> Inside test1()
>>> Inside test2()
>>> Inside test3()
>>> Foo is pretty.
```

Answer (score 3):

```
def test1():
  def test2():
    print "Here!"
  test2() #You need to call the function the usual way

test1() #Prints "Here!"
```

Note that the `test2` function is not available outside of `test1`. If, for instance, you tried to call `test2()` later in your code, you would get an error.

Comment: What if I have more than one function inside `test1`?

Comment: @zachgates They can still only be called inside test1.

Comment: Any functions defined inside of test1 will only be available inside of test1. If you want to use the function later, you need to define it outside of test1

Comment: @sredmond: Or return it from `test1`.

Answer (score 0):

You can't, since `test2` stops existing once `test1()` has returned. Either return it from the outer function or only ever call it from there.

Comment: This is right if he means "how do I call `test2` from outside `test1`", but not if he's asking how to call it from inside `test1`.  (The question isn't clear on this.)